# UITableViewCell doesn't flip subViews for RTL objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using NSLocalization in my app and unfortunately, views are not switching their frame's origin for RTL.

**English**
[image]

**Arabic**
[image]

For Arabic, image should be at left side of labels, but it is not happening throughout the app. Only labels are changing text alignment, everything else is same.

Why it is not happening. I have set semantics as well in case of Arabic:

```
[[UITextView appearance]setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight]
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
```

and for English:

```
[[UITextView appearance]setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[[UITableViewCell appearance]setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have the "Leading" and "Trailing" two constraints( rather than Left and Right ), you'd better use Masonry . When you have some constraints , you could use SemanticContentAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Auto Layout or do you calculate the frames yourself? With Auto Layout you simply need to use leading and trailing edges instead of left and right, respectively. With manual layout you need to do the flipping yourself, iOS can't do that automatically.